# My interrupt routine does not access an array correctly

Tags: c++, static, interrupt, volatile

Update to this - seems like there are some issues with trig functions in math.h (using MPIDE compiler)- it is no wonder I couldn't see this with my debugger which was using its own math.h and therefore giving me the expected (correct solutions). I found this out by accident on the microchip boards and instead implemented a 'fast sine/cosine' algorithm instead (see devmaster dot com for this). My ISR and ColourWheel array now work perfectly.

I must say that, as a fairly newcomer to C/C++ I have spent a lot of hours reviewing and re-reviewing my own code for errors. The last possible thing on my mind was that some very basic functions that were no doubt written decades ago could give such problems.

I suppose I would have seen the problem earlier myself if I'd had access to a screen dump of the actual array but, as my chip is connected to my led cube I've no way to access the data in the chip directly.

Hey, ho !! - when I get the chance I'll post a link to a u tube video showing the wave function that I've now been able to program and looks pretty good on my LED cube.

Russell

ps
Thank you all so very much for your help here - it stopped me giving up completely by giving me some avenues to chase down - certainly did not know much about endianess before this so learned about that and some systematic ways to go about a robust debugging approach.

I have a problem when trying to access an array in an interrupt routine.

The following is a snippet of code from inside the ISroutine.

```
if (CubeStatusArray[x][y][Layer]){
    for(int8_t bitpos=7; bitpos >= 0; bitpos--){
        if((ColourWheel[Colour]>>16)&(1<<bitpos)) { // This line seems to cause trouble
            setHigh(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);
        }
        else {
            setLow(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);
        }
    }
}
..........
```

ColourWheel[Colour] has been declared as follows at the start of my program (outside any function)

```
static volatile uint32_t ColourWheel[255]; //this is the array from which
                                           //the colours can be obtained -
                                           //all set as 3 eight bit numbers
                                           //using up 24 bits of a 32bit
                                           //unsigned int.
```

What this snippet of code is doing is taking each bit of an eight bit segment of the code and setting the port/pin high or low accordingly with MSB first (I then have some other code which updates a TLC5940 IC LED driver chip for each high/low on the pin and the code goes on to take the green and blue 8 bits in a similar way).

This does not work and my colours output to my LEDs behave incorrectly.

However, if I change the code as follows then the routine works

```
if (CubeStatusArray[x][y][Layer]){
    for(int8_t bitpos=7; bitpos >= 0; bitpos--){
        if(0b00000000111111111110101010111110>>16)&(1<<bitpos)) { // This line seems to cause trouble
            setHigh(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);}
        else {
            setLow(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);
        }
    }
}
..........
```

(the actual binary number in the line is irrelevant (the first 8 bits are always zero, the next 8 bits represent a red colour, the next a blue colour etc)

So why does the ISR work with the fixed number but not if I try to use a number held in an array.??

Following is the actual code showing the full RGB update:

```
                if (CubeStatusArray[x][y][Layer]){
                      for(int8_t bitpos=7; bitpos >= 0; bitpos--){
                        {if((ColourWheel[Colour]>>16)&(1<<bitpos))
                        {setHigh(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);}
                        else
                        {setLow(SINRED_PORT,SINRED_PIN);}}
                        {if((ColourWheel[Colour]>>8)&(1<<bitpos))
                        {setHigh(SINGREEN_PORT,SINGREEN_PIN);}
                        else
                        {setLow(SINGREEN_PORT,SINGREEN_PIN);}}
                        {if((ColourWheel[Colour])&(1<<bitpos))
                        {setHigh(SINBLUE_PORT,SINBLUE_PIN);}
                        else
                        {setLow(SINBLUE_PORT,SINBLUE_PIN);}}
                        pulse(SCLK_PORT, SCLK_PIN);
                        pulse(GSCLK_PORT, GSCLK_PIN);
                        Data_Counter++;
                        GSCLK_Counter++;                          }
```

Comment: What are the endianess of your computer and device?

Comment: You say that it does not work with the Array.  What's incorrect?  Also, have you tried running both segments of code and compare results?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need to expand a bit on what is going on in the array to explain fully.

Comment: The array contains 255 separate 'colours'. I have defined each colour as being a combination of either Red/Green, Red/Blue or Green/Blue. So the 2nd 8 bits in the 32 bit number (which represents blue) starts off as FF and goes down to 0 while at the same time the 3rd 8 bits in the 32 bit number which represents blue starts off at 0 and goes up to FF. For example 0b00000000 11110000 00001111 00000000 (I've separated the number up for ease of view) would mean the first four bits of red get set and the lowest four bits of green get set (i.e mainly blue with a bit of green).

Comment: To finish this point what I am seeing is only primary colours (of differing brightness) when I use a colour from the array, but when I use a binary number I see a correct 'blend' of colours. I want to be able to cycle through the colour array that I created in my main prog.

Comment: Have you made certain "0 <= Colour < 255"?

Comment: Further on `ColourWheel[Colour]`.  Rather than reference it 8x in your each r,g,b loop, assign a local uint32_t to its value.  As this is an ISR, time is important.. Also other higher levels interrupts, in theory, could change its value.

Comment: How long are you displaying each color?

Comment: In respect of the endianess piece, probably a bit more explanation. I am updating an 8x8x8 array of leds one layer at a time. So 64 leds. Each led on a layer can be thought of as being one of 0 to 63. I update each of these leds at a time from 63 down to zero. Each led has three colours and I need to set each bit for each colour simultaneously. I therefore look at the led number (referenced by x,y) and if it is not coloured fill with 12 zero bits. If it is coloured then I use the code above to set its colour. (hope this makes sense)

Comment: Each colour is displayed on a 1 in 8 duty cycle for each layer in the 8x8x8 cube - fast enough to ensure Persistence of Vision - so each colour is flashing at least over 80hz  (which is about the limit at which one can detect flicker)

Comment: I'm wondering if your color selection algorithm is producing a smooth variation of colors, using the red/green example ff0000 is pure red, d02f00 is also very red just a little dimmer/darker.  Your hard coded example is ffeabe, kind of a cream/tan color.  Notice high values for all 3 of the rgb components -a feature your selection algorithm lacks.

Comment: Could the longer time needed to do `ColourWheel[Colour]>>16` vs. `0b00000000111111111110101010111110>>16` be messing up the proper signal for "other code which updates a TLC5940 IC LED driver"?  If so, the various solutions that speed things up would help.

Comment: Mojc sorry about the choice of my original binary number - this is not one that the algorithm would choose - mocj you are right my hard coded example was just some random number, I have used a variety of different hard coded numbers and they work as I would want.. I inspected the array through a debugger also and it did give a smooth fall in one colour as the other colour increased

Comment: @rjamjb - right, my point was that from ff0000 to d02f00 are practically the same color - just a little 'darker' - that is 47 of 255 of your total color selections that are very similar

Comment: @rjamjb - what i mean is almost half of your array is essentially 2 colors

Comment: @mocj Here I thought the 8 bits/primary was a 0 to 255 color level.  Re-reading, it appears to be 1 of 9 levels/primary as it is the _number_ of bits set (0 to 8 bits)/primary used to control brightness.  Hmmm.  Given the persistence of an LED, 0b10000000 may be just as bright as 0b11000000 and not twice as bright.  If this your understanding?

Comment: @chux No, my understanding is that each byte is a 0-255 color value. I was assuming the color array looks something like the following (assuming red/green selection): index[0] = 0x00ff0000, [1] = 0x00fe0100, [2] = 0x00fd0200, ... [254] = 0x0001fe00, [255] = 0x0000ff00.  If this is truly the case then it may explain the primary colors of varying brightness that rjamjb is seeing.  If you open an image editor and start looking at the colors that correspond to the rgb values in the color array, the first 20% or so look almost like the same color red with varying brightness...

Comment: Just for clarity this is how my color scheme works. If i was only working with two colors 4 bits each (say Red and Green)  then Colour Wheel[0] would be 1111 0000 (i.e all red - first four bits). Colour wheel[1] would be 1110 0001 (i.e 1 less on red and 1 bit of green) Colourwheel[2] would be 1101 0010 etc etc until Colourwheel[14] 0001    1110 and Colourwheel[15] 0000 1111. In between i'd have half of one colour and half of the other and it would be very clear that I have (eg yellow or cyan) a non- primary colour.

Comment: My mixing is not quite linear(because the leds are not quite linear in brightness when viewed per the scale of 1 to 8 bits) so that the middle colour is actually about 70% of the brightness of the max of each colour (and not 50%) [ps excuse my Colour vs Color - I'm a Brit and add the extra 'u' by habbit]

Comment: What is the sizeof(int)?  What is the type of `Colour`?

Comment: OP: "ColourWheel array was somehow being overwritten or changed as it was passed from my main function to the ISR".  Please clarify how you _passed_ ColourWheel.  It is `static`, in global memory.

Comment: volatile uint32_t Colour; is declared before any function. I assume that the sizeof(int)? means the size of a basic integer. I'm not too sure about this - my debugger (MPLAB) has the int as 32 bit and and uint8_t as 8 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the missing `(` after `if` is a typo.

The indicated research technique, in the absence of a debugger, is:

1. Confirm one more time that test `if( ( 0b00000000111111111110101010111110 >> 16 ) & ( 1 << bitpos ) )` works.  Collect (print) the result for each `bitpos`
2. Store `0b00000000111111111110101010111110` in element 0 of the array.  Repeat with `if( ( ColourWheel[0] >> 16 ) & ( 1 << bitpos ) )`.  Collect results and compare with base case.
3. Store `0b00000000111111111110101010111110` in all elements of the array.  Repeat with `if( ( ColourWheel[Colour] >> 16 ) & ( 1 << bitpos ) )` for several different Colour values (assigned manually, though).  Collect results and compare with base case.
4. Store `0b00000000111111111110101010111110` in all elements of the array.  Repeat with `if( ( ColourWheel[Colour] >> 16 ) & ( 1 << bitpos ) )` with a value for Colour normally assigned.  Collect results and compare with base case.
5. Revert to the original program and retest.  Collect results and compare with base case.

Comment: Yes - was a typo in my original - several things to work through here. I will work through and repost. I don't think that I have an easy way to print out results - I have been running my code through MPLAB X (I'm programming a Chipkit uno32) to debug and check variable changes at each step.

Comment: Working through this I eventually came up with a solution but a workaround really. When I actually placed the numbers in directly (eg storing 0x00F0F000 (Red F0, Green F0) I got the yellow as expected, similarly 0000F0F0 (Green F0, Blue F0) gave Cyan and 0x00F0F0F0 gave white. So I tried a different approach and filled the array directly by setting each element of the array instead of filling via a formula.... so

Comment: The first couple of lines are  void fillagaincolourwheel(void){
ColourWheel[0]=0b00000000111111110000000000000000;    
ColourWheel[1]=0b00000000111111100000000000000100;    
ColourWheel[2]=0b00000000111111100000000000001001; etc right through to ColourWheel[254]=0b00000000111111100000010000000000;}

Comment: This tells me that the original ColourWheel array was somehow being overwritten or changed as it was passed from my main function to the ISR. I know that the original ColourWheel function was generating the correct colours as I used it in a debugger to generate all the values that I cut and paste into the alternative ColourWheel update.

Answer (score 0):

Confident that the value in `ColourWheel[Colour]` is not as expected or unstable.  Validate the index range and access once.  Code speed enhancement included.

---

[Edit] If the receiving end does not like the slower signal changes caused by replacing a constant with `ColourWheel[Colour]>>16`, more effcient code may solve this.

---

```
 if (CubeStatusArray[x][y][Layer]){
   uint32_t value = 0;
   uint32_t maskR = 0x800000UL;
   uint32_t maskG = 0x8000UL;
   uint32_t maskB = 0x80UL;
   if ((Colour >= 0) && (Colour < 255)) {
     value = ColourWheel[Colour];
   }
   // All you need to do is shift 'value'
   for(int8_t bitpos=7; bitpos >= 0; bitpos--){
     { if( (value & maskR) // set red
     }
     { if( (value & maskG) // set green
     }
     { if( (value & maskB) // set blue
     }
     value <<= 1;
   }
```

Comment: I was always partial to something like: for (uint8_t mask = 0x80; mask; mask >>= 1 )

Comment: @mocj Yes, followed that many times, though I prefer `unsigned`.  Here we can take advantage that `value` holds all 24 color bits and can be shifted 24 times, alway testing the same bit.  Static position bit test code well in embedded processors.

Comment: Chux, I'm not sure that this will work. Essentially I need to set a red bit/green bit/blue bit (on their respective pins on my chipkit) then send a pulse to update the Driver ICs. I then move to the next RGB bits and set three pins and send a pulse to update the driver ICs etc. I can't set all red, then all green then all blue.

Comment: @rjamjb You are correct.  I mis-read your code snippet and have amended my answer.

Comment: Chux, thank you for this I've used it as the basis to remaster the bit updates - it clearly saves quite a few cycles in my ISR - (even more when you think that this snippet of code is repeated 64 times for each voxel). Quite ingenious. I'm fairly new to c/c++, I guess you get better at identifying time savings with practice. I've got to a solution to the colour issue but really with a work-around rather than understanding the original problem. See my response to Rossi above.

Comment: BTW: If `ColourWheel` is not changing in the ISR, consider removing `volatile`.  Instead, you may need to protect it (make it atomic) by preventing interrupts during the write.

Comment: I did wonder whether there was something like this going on and I had been changing some of the key variables with qualifiers static/const/volatile until I'd got quite confused about the impact across my various functions (while at the same time worrying that the compiler would slow things down in my ISR by not being efficient) - I'm not sure how you work out whats best in these situations!!!!. I shall try a bit more on this :-)